# Keeping API keys and access details for the database secure

Tags: git, security, node.js, nodejitsu

What is best practice for keeping API keys and access details for the database secure?

We will be deploying with Nodejitsus `jitsu deploy` so my thought is to have a config file that will not be part of git.

Our current config file which I will have .gitignore'd

```
module.exports = (app) ->

    app.configure 'development', ->

        global.config = 
            dbUrl: 'mongodb://username:password@host:port/closet'
            foursquare:
                client_id: 'xxx'
                client_secret: 'xxx'
                redirect_uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/account/auth/foursquare/done'

        return

    app.configure 'production', ->

        global.config = 
            dbUrl: 'mongodb://username:password@host:port/closet'
            foursquare:
                client_id: 'yyy'
                client_secret: 'yyy'
                redirect_uri: 'http://example.com/account/auth/foursquare/done'

        return


    return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually what I do is store my configuration in a `config.json`, add it to my `.gitignore`, and then include a `.npmignore` so that npm doesn't use the `.gitignore` to decide what to bundle. That way, git doesn't add the config.json yet jitsu bundles it on deploy.

env variables, as booyaa suggested, will also work.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the API keys (and other secrets) as environmental variables using `jitsu env` command. Then use process.env to grab these variables within your node.js app.